# Why my meteor app create "hiddendiv common" div tags?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, meteor, materialize

I'm wondering why my meteor app create some tags like this for no reasons?

```
<div class="hiddendiv common"></div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor is not responsible for inserting this markup inside your application DOM, it's the MaterializeCSS framework that is inserting this `hiddenDiv` as you can tell from the source code : https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/forms.js#L98

Apparently, is has something to do with automatic resizing of `textarea`s.

Comment: Thank you! How you find that i use materialize ?

Comment: I did not, Google did :) I'm using Materialize too so I was curious.

Comment: I searched for "hiddendiv common" and found nothing. What was your search?

Comment: I searched for `hiddendiv common` too : first result is the github issue I found the info on (https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/1427) and second result is now this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide this div, but your text area will not resize when this is added.

```
.hiddendiv {
    display: none;
}
```